# RNAppAuth, iOS build failed, Unknown type name 'namespace', react-native-app-auth

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, appauth

I am trying to add `react-native-app-auth` to existing, but quite fresh project with Expo.
I'm following your setup guide, so doing following steps:

- `yarn add react-native-app-auth@2.2.0 --dev`
- Add `pod 'AppAuth', '>= 0.91'`
- `cd iso && pod install`
- `react-native link` (EDIT: from root path of the project)

And I get:

```
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-app-auth ios dependency
rnpm-install WARN ERRGROUP Group 'Libraries' does not exist in your Xcode project. We have created it automatically for you.
rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-app-auth has been successfully linked
```

which looks fine.

Then when I build in XCode i get the following error:

[image]

After searching the web I found it may be connected with compilator I changed it use Objective-C++:

[image]

and now I get more errors:

[image]

I also tried:

- Changing Target version to `9.0`
- Doing it again
- Praying

Nothing helps :( Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145)

app.js

```
{
    "expo": {
        "sdkVersion": "26.0.0",
        "ios": {
        "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxx.xxx",
        "publishBundlePath": "ios/mobile-xxx/Supporting/shell-app.bundle",
        "publishManifestPath": "ios/mobile-xxx/Supporting/shell-app-manifest.json"
        },
        "android": {
        "package": "com.xxx.xxx"
        },
        "name": "mobile-xxx",
        "slug": "mobile-xxx",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "isDetached": true,
        "entryPoint": "./index.js",
        "detach": {
        "scheme": "exp997ce9c6b4fd43cfa14f4eede063ecf5",
        "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.4.4-sdk26.0.0-3bd935c7-cdd3-4002-8e44-4df857a675f2.tar.gz",
        "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.4.0-sdk26.0.0-e63d9209-070c-4118-b06b-c60e82da0b66.tar.gz"
        }
    }
}
```

package.js

```
{
    "name": "mobile-xxx",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest-expo": "26.0.0",
        "react-native-app-auth": "2.2.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
    },
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "^26.0.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
        "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-app-auth": "^2.2.0",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "redux": "^3.7.2"
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have just setup a fresh Expo app following [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/16/build-react-native-authentication-oauth-2) guide and have exactly the same error.

Comment: Did you run link from the project root? Not clear if you did from the steps you listed.

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for being unclear @MichaelCheng

Comment: I believe it has something to do with `boost-for-react-native`, from the error logs.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is an import in header search paths, which searches in the whole `/ios` folder:
`$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/**`

If you happen to use Expo and CocoaPods, there will be `boost-for-react-native` as a dependency inside your Pods folder. In fact, any package depending on boost will cause this problem. XCode tries to build boost as well, but it has some non-ObjC files, so it will fail.

**In order to fix the issue:**

Open RNAppAuth.xcodeproj, switch to Build Settings tab and search for header search paths. Replace line `$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/**` with

```
"$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME",
"$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/AppAuth/**",
```

Please note that these changes will disappear after using npm install (or yarn). To make these changes permanent, you can use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Edit: this issue has been fixed, using the latest version of the package should work now.

Comment: This solution not working for boost-for-react-native library.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me debug my problem.